# How can I fix the Jekyll error "Liquid Exception: Invalid Date:..." when building my hugo-apero website using blogdown?

Tags: r, build, jekyll, blogdown

When I build my [hugo-apero website](https://github.com/Layalchristine24/Layalchristine24.github.io) in GitHub, I get the following error:

```
  Liquid Exception: Invalid Date: '{}' is not a valid datetime. in /_layouts/default.html
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Invalid Date: '{}' is not a valid datetime.
```

Despite this error, I still can get my website deployed but I would like to understand how to fix this error because it is really annoying. I don't understand why this error message suddenly appears, since I never had any /_layouts/default.html file in my repo.

I had a look to similar examples (https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-on-mac-could-not-read-file-and-invalid-date-error-using-bundle-exec-jekyll-serve/7664/6, [https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-site),...) but did not find any answer that matches my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to build a Hugo site with Jekyll?

Comment: Yes, it appears that I set up my configuration so that my Hugo site is built with Jekyll, without knowing the details at the time I created my site (one year ago). I must have read some tutorial that wasn't right for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the empty file `.nojekyll` to the root of the project. Thank you @Matt Bannert for your advice. See [Deploying static site to GitHub pages needs .nojekyll file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2029).

Answer (score 1):

@BenjaminW. is on the right track here. Both Hugo and jekyll are so-called static website generators. That is, they use go (in the case of Hu**go**) or ruby (in the case of jekyll) to generate HTML/CSS/JS (which browsers can work with) from easy-to-edit `.yaml`, `.toml`, etc. files.

You are using the R blogdown package as an additional wrapper on top of hugo/jekyll. Afaik, blogdown can handle both jekyll and hugo, but you need to make a choice (see also here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/jekyll.html)

Took a brief look at your code and was under the impression that you were mixing both generators. FWIW, since you are starting here and it may not be too late,  I can warmly recommend https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/
to R users working on their personal website / blog. The CLI is really nice, well documented and state-of-the-art.

Comment: Thank you @Matt Bannert. I tried to remove .ruby-version and Gemfile (see respective [commit](https://github.com/Layalchristine24/Layalchristine24.github.io/commit/d45277ce099dede1160c98cb012f80e9fd412b79) but the same error still shows up. Should I do something with the [GitHub Action](https://github.com/Layalchristine24/Layalchristine24.github.io/actions/workflows/pages/pages-build-deployment) like removing one workflow or anything else?

Comment: Should I process as described in [Host on GitHub | Hugo](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/)? As I already use Netlify, I am not sure whether it is needed to have any GitHub Actions.

Comment: I think you're mixing a few concepts here. Imo, you should first try to get it going locally on your own computer to make sure you understand what is going on and which tool is used to render the website. Both GitHub actions and netlify offer you to not only host static files but also run the rendering on their servers. I am always in a favor of a local dev environment.